# Add a scope bar to filter search results in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, search, filter

I have a search field in my Cocoa app and I'd like to add a scope bar like in Mail to filter search results (in Mail you can filter search results by selecting the folder in which you want to search for e-mails). This bar (like in Mail) should appear only when the user enters some text into the search field and should contain some buttons that the user can toggle to filter the search results. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about by using [MGScopeBar](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/10/28/mgscopebar/)?